# Output SQL with log4j in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: sql, logging, jasper-reports, log4j, jaspersoft-studio

Some background first. I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.0 Final and have followed the instructions [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-apache-commons-logging-and-log4j-jaspersoft-studio) to setup log4j. I'm trying to get log4j to output the SQL query when my report is run. I have a problem with the query and need to see the SQL outputed by Jaspersoft Studio. I have a working datasource setup so connection to the datasource is not a problem.

I thought that following the instructions at the link above and then adding `log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter=debug` to my `log4j-config.properties` file would let me see the output SQL, but it's not working.

To run the report I compile the jrxml and then click the preview tab. Since I followed the instructions in the link above, shouldn't the SQL be outputed to my log4j log file when I do that?

I need to get this working so I can fix my query. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please add net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter = ALL to logging-config.properties...also run you Jasper Studio as administrator. It works for me..i am basically using the Java util logging(-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/jsslog/config/logging-config.properties) and not the apache log4j logging.